# How to combine 2 lapply() functions to create a boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, lapply

So I have this code and trying to create a boxplot and add the p values to show significantly different groups. First is I created a boxplot using `lapply()` function giving me 3 boxplots from dataframe `1.3.A`, `2.2.A`, and `1.1.B`.
I also analyszed the `Height` and `Age` columns using `kruskal.test()` and `dunnTest()`. I was able to get the `P.adj` from the dunn's test and saved it into another variable (I saved it in variable `poo` which is a list containing several dataframes of the pvalues). What I am trying to do is to incorporate the pvalues from `poo` to the `wales` boxplots using `stat_pvlaue_manual()`. However, since `poo` is list, I don't know how to incorporate the pvalues in the boxplots which returns an error:

```
  can't find the y.position variable 'y.position' in the data
Called from: .valide_y_position(y.position, data)
```

Is what I am doing even possible? I'm sorry I am new to R.  I am just after the significant values and place it to the boxplot I created. I am using `stat_pvalue_manual()` becasue the pvalues are from a dunnTest so. I tried using `stat_compare_means()` but could not make it work as well. The thing that make this harder is that everything is within `lapply` and I do not know how to correctly incorporate these this all together.

```
wales <- lapply(df_list, function(p) ggboxplot(p, x = "Person", y = c("Height", "Age"), 
                                                     combine = TRUE, 
                                                     x.text.angle = 360, 
                                                     orientation = "horizontal", 
                                                     ylab = "Measurement (cm)",
                                                     ggtheme = theme_gray()) + 
                                                     font("xy.text", size = 7, color = "black") + 
                                                     theme(legend.position = "None", 
                                                     axis.text.x =element_text(color = "black")) + 
                                                     lapply(poo,  function(g) stat_pvalue_manual(label = "P.adj", 
                                                     y.position = 7), data = g))
```

Here is my sample data:

```
df_list <- list(
  `1.3.A` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,  ~Age, 
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,    15,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,  17,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,   19,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,    22,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,  21,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,    20

    ),
  `2.2.A` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,   ~Age,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,     18,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,   18,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,    19,
       "Alex",    175L,     75L,    25,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,   27,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,    26
    ), 
  `1.1.B` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,    ~Age,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,       22,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,     23,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,      25, 
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,       27,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,     18,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L,      19   
    )
)
```

Comment: what is `klosh` and what is your dataset `g`?

Comment: Oops, sorry, it should be ‘poo’ and ‘g’ is the dataframe that pertains to the dataframes inside poo

Comment: one issue with trying to specify the manual pvalue is that you have two panels for each figure (one related to each y value) . The label argument only takes one input so it will repeat the same p-value for both panels. Is it possible to separate height and age into different graphics?

Comment: @Mike yup, i can do that. I’ll separate ‘Age’ and ‘Height’ into two separate graphs using the function in ‘wales’

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely familiar with `ggboxplot()` or `stat_pvalue_manual()` but what you can do is use one loop and one y outcome to get the p-values on each graph. `poo` is just a list of p-values, and in `wales` I am using one loop with the values of 1 to 3 as the list and then subsetting both lists `df_list` and `poo` based on position.

```
 poo <- list(dat1 = data.frame(group1 = 0.01, group2 = NA),
             dat2 =data.frame(group1 =.09, group2 = NA)
             ,dat3 = data.frame(group1 = .9, group2 = NA))
 
 wales <- lapply(1:length(df_list), function(p) ggboxplot(df_list[[p]], x = "Person", y = c("Height"), 
                                                combine = TRUE, 
                                                x.text.angle = 360, 
                                                orientation = "horizontal", 
                                                ylab = "Measurement (cm)",
                                                ggtheme = theme_gray()) + 
                   font("xy.text", size = 7, color = "black") + 
                   theme(legend.position = "None", 
                         axis.text.x =element_text(color = "black"))+
                stat_pvalue_manual(label = "group1", y.position = 7, data = poo[[p]]))
```